# Zend Framework - Dojo form encoding problem

Tags: zend-framework, forms, encoding, dojo

in my Zend Framework App i wanna use Dojo Form.
I have problem with encoding i guess.

when i add element into form with label containing some specila chars like éíá it works but it doenst show any label!

```
$this->addElement ( new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_TextBox ( array (
    'name' => 'TextBox',
    'label' => 'áíé', 
    'required' => true, 
    'InvalidMessage' => 'Invalid', 
    'trim' => true, 
    'propercase' => true ) ) );
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Whats the error? I think you could also just use $this->addElement('TextBox', array(....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
i´ve saved file  with same encoding(utf8) (previously was win1250)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it but have you tried setting utf-8 on the form:

```
->setAttrib('accept-charset', 'utf-8'); or 'accept-charset' => 'utf-8'
```

It maybe also worth checking you're view is set to utf-8 too.

```
$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: No, it isnt working. I have tried set accept-charset. Also I have already had encoding in view - <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />